# Do these surfaces intersect?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, real-algebraic-geometry

For any real numbers $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots a_{6}$ and $b_{1},b_{2},\cdots b_{6}$
with $\sum_{i=1}^{6}a_{i}^{2}=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{6}b_{i}^{2}=1$,
does the equation $$ x_{1}^{2}x_{2}^{2}x_{3}^{2}x_{4}^{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{6}a_{i}x_{i}\right)^{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{6}b_{i}x_{i}\right)^{2}=1 $$ always have a solution $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots x_{6}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{6}x_{i}^{2}=6$? Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? what is your background? this may be suitable in math stack exchange if you can edit this mentioning what all you know

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik  I have tried special cases and the answer is yes for the special cases; and on the other hand, I could not find any counter-example. Best regards.

Comment: which special cases have you tried? add that in the question.. what techniques you know about intersection of surfaces add that in the question

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik  I tried the special cases of choosing some of them to be 0 's or 1's. I am not in the area of algebraic surface, but this question is about intersection of surfaces, which I believe the researchers in the area of surfaces or related can answer. Thanks.

Comment: There have been a relatively large number of edits in a short space of time. It would be preferable to work out before hand what one wants to write, and then stick with it

Comment: The editing or rephrasing was due to no answer received for the original question. Best regards.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Just wondering if you know the answer to the question or have any helpful idea that could lead an answer to the question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mathers1 sorry, can not think of any way to proceed

Comment: This should be possible to answer using cylindrical algebraic decomposition.

Comment: @gyashfe Thank you for your comment. Could you please let us know what cylindrical algebraic decomposition is exactly and show us how should it possible to use it to get the correct answer to this question? Thanks.

Comment: @mathers1 it is an algorithm for quantifier elimination over a real closed field (see also the Tarski-Seidenberg theorem). You can find it, together with some computer implementations, on the internet.

Comment: @gyashfe But this question is about the existence of solutions and the equation is generic. How could the algorithm that you referred to be used to get the correct answer to this question? Thanks.

Comment: @mathers1 The algorithm can directly take as input a quantified formula of the form: $\forall a_1,\ldots,a_6,b_1,\ldots,b_6 \exists x_1,\ldots,x_6: \lnot(\sum a_i ^2 = \sum b_i ^2 = 1) \vee (\prod_{i=1}^4 x_i ^2 (\sum a_i x_i)^2 (\sum b_i x_i)^2 = 1)$ and return a truth value. If there are free variables, it gives as output the precise conditions on them which make the formula true (these conditions are given by polynomial equations and inequalities).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is "yes" though the argument is rather ad hoc and doesn't generalize to vectors in more general positions.

We have $6$ unit vectors $v_j$ out of which the first $4$ are pairwise orthogonal and want to show that there exists a vector of length $\sqrt 6$ such that $\prod_{j=1}^6 |\langle x,v_j\rangle|\ge 1$ (to get below $1$ is trivial). Consider all sums $y=\sum_{j=1}^6\varepsilon_j v_j$ where $\varepsilon_j=\pm 1$ and choose the one with the largest length. Replacing some $v_j$ with $-v_j$, if necessary, we can assume WLOG that it is $y=\sum_j v_j$. Comparing $y$ with $y-2v_j$ (one sign flip), we see that $\langle y,v_j\rangle\ge 1$ for all $j$. Unfortunately, $y$ is a bit long, but it cannot get the length greater than $4$ (the $4$ pairwise orthogonal vectors produce length $2$) and we have
$$
\|y\|^2=\sum_j \langle y,v_j\rangle=:\sum_j (1+u_j), \quad 0\le u_j\le 3
$$ 
Reducing the length to $\sqrt 6$ means that we have to multiply $y$ by $\left(1+\frac 16\sum_j u_j\right)^{-1/2}$, so it suffices to show that 
$$
\prod_j(1+u_j)\ge \left(1+\frac 16\sum_j u_j\right)^3
$$
i.e.
$$
\prod_j(1+u_j)^{1/3}\ge 1+\frac 16\sum_j u_j.
$$
However, on $[0,3]$, we have $(1+u)^{1/3}\ge 1+\frac u6$ (the LHS is concave, so it is enough to check the endpoints) and Bernoulli finishes the story.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you multiply $y$ by $\left(1+\frac 16\sum_j u_j\right)^{-1/2}$, how would you have $\langle y,v_j\rangle\ge 1$ for all $j$? Thanks.

Comment: @mathers1 I would not. I would just have the product $\prod_j \langle x,v_j\rangle$ equal to $\left(1+\frac 16\sum_j u_j\right)^{-3}\prod_j(1+u_j)$ and the rest of the post is about showing that it is still $\ge 1$.